# pip stops working after upgrading Python on OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, upgrade

I encountered an installation issue with `pip` after upgrading Python on OS X. I upgraded to the latest Python 3.11 using homebrew. This also install pip with the latest version. I then redirected my Python path from `/usr/local/bin/python3.11` to `/usr/local/bin/python`. Everything worked great, except my site-packages were no longer found (as expected).

**The issue:** when I tried to import packages using `pip` or `pip3` I got the following error:

```bash
$ pip3 install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/build_env.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.rich.console import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    _IMPORT_CWD = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Other older SO solutions did not seem to help, including upgrading permissions.

**Question**: How do I import packages with pip?

Answer (score 2):

As the OS X operating system relies on the originally installed Python, you cannot really get rid of it without creating a lot of headaches.

The homebrew upgrade installed a version of `pip` for Python 3.11 callable as `pip3.11`. Just call this version of pip to install packages for the latest version of Python. Example:

```bash
$ pip3.11 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Obtaining dependency information for numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/57/3cb8131a0e6d559501e088d3e685f4122e9ff9104c4b63e4dfd3a577b491/numpy-1.25.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Downloading numpy-1.25.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.6 kB)
Downloading numpy-1.25.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (20.8 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 20.8/20.8 MB 22.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.25.2
```